# Numerical integration with Numba

Tags: python, performance, numerical-methods, numba

I'm a bit new to working with Numba, but I got the gist of it. I wonder if there any more advanced tricks to make four nested `for` loops even faster that what I have now. In particular, I need to calculate the following integral:

$$
G_B(\mathbf X, T) = \Lambda \int_\Omega G(\mathbf X, \mathbf X', T) W(\mathbf X', T) \ d\mathbf X' \\
G(\mathbf X, \mathbf X', T) = \frac{1}{2\pi S_0^2} \exp\left[-\frac{\left| \mathbf X -\mathbf X'\right|^2}{2[S_0(1+EB(\mathbf X, T))]^2}\right]
$$

Where \$B\$ is a 2D array, and \$S_0\$ and \$E\$ are certain parameters. My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, double

def calc_gb_gauss_2d(b,s0,e,dx):
    n,m=b.shape
    norm = 1.0/(2*np.pi*s0**2)
    gb = np.zeros((n,m))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            sigma = 2.0*(s0*(1.0+e*b[i,j]))**2
            for ii in range(n):
                for jj in range(m):
                    gb[i,j]+=np.exp(-(((i-ii)*dx)**2+((j-jj)*dx)**2)/sigma)
            gb[i,j]*=norm
    return gb

calc_gb_gauss_2d_nb = njit(double[:, :](double[:, :],double,double,double))(calc_gb_gauss_2d)
```

For and input array of size 256×256 the calculation speed is:

```
In [4]: a=random.random((256,256))

In [5]: %timeit calc_gb_gauss_2d_nb(a,0.1,1.0,0.5)
The slowest run took 8.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 1s per loop
```

Comparison between pure Python and Numba calculation speed give me this picture:
[image: Comparative performance plot]

Is there any way to optimize my code for better performance?

Answer (score 2):

When using `njit` as a decorator you have access to multiple options that you might want to try, such as:

- fastmath
- parallel
- nogil

I will only focus on `fastmath` and `parallel`. There must be someone more competent to deal with the `nogil` argument.

## [Fastmath](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html#fastmath)

This options let you relax some operations (diminishing the precision) for shorter computation time. It can be set to `True`/`False` but you can be more picky with the options you want to make faster.

## [Parallel](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html#parallel-true) and [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#numba-parallel)

It doesn't have the freedom of conventional parallel projects such as OMP/MPI, but it supports the `prange` directive. You have to explicitly choose the loop you want to parallelize. Also you might need to slightly modify the code - for example, creating a variable to compute reductions or "private" to each thread/process.

In addition to that, you should not only test times, but also test your integration scheme on test cases when you have the exact solution or at best an approximation.